# How to gain access to :app class from library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I have a case that I need to access the :app project classes from the library project. (not res, java classes)
I have searched and the answer was to implement the :app in the library Gradle file like this :

```
implementation project(':app')
```

and then after Gradling I got these errors:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
```

then I searched again and I thought that could be the circular implementing two project with each other, then I add the third android library to be the connector of the :app and :myLib even with that the errors was the same. implementing two android libraries with each was not so problem even circular type but with the main app directory...
so any help?
and again I have to do it this way and there is no other way, for example, using abstract classes or ... my case is special cause this is no ordinary app and is gonna be an android frameWork not just an app. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be right and this could be the case of **`Circular Dependency`**. But having an **`Android application`** as a **`Dependency`** to a **`android library`** does not make sense.

A much better solution would be to **`extract`** those files that you want to use from **`app`** into a seperate **`new module`**, mark this new module as **`android-library`**, and implement this **`new module`** into the space where you want to access these newly isolated classes.

Comment: the problem is that my project is a framework for android and I need to always get a class from the android project and with knowing that my 'app is running the MainAcrtivity from the library not :app directory' so I need to access it really. is there any way?

Comment: I do not understand when you say that your app is a framework. Android itself is a framework. Isolating the classes that you want to use in app module into a different module can still be used in app. Extracting them will solve your problem of bringing your app module as a dependency.

Comment: we are making a framework with new ideas and new java android ways but for the android framework itself just like how Express is for Node(and I know node is not a framework, however). so for our idea, we need to access the classes. anyway, thanks.

Comment: Please describe how modularizing the app will work in this case?

Comment: Correct, the app is going to just run a single Activity(our Custom Activity) but the point is in all of the Screens we have run just one and for changing view we just reCreated that one Activity and setContentViewing again. so Why? cause of very very point we get I can call the temporary variables, accessing variable from each screen, leverage the code and many many features we thought and is working nice in the last version without this routing... but with this, it's going to be a big huge step ahead.

Comment: I would like to give my closing thoughts on this: Single Activity architecture is not new in android. That single activity should be in :app module and other library modules can be dependencies to this :app module. You originally said that you have some classes in :app module which you want to use in other modules. A good solution is to modularize the :app module. Hope you''ll find something else if not this.